# GIT and versioning sections of a repository

Tags: git, visual-studio

Does anyone know how to version sections of a repository?

I understand that you can create a tag as a version within GIT. I was wondering if you could version sections of and application. For example, I have an application that has several sections and each section currently has an individual version (legacy set up).

Is there a way to maintain the versioning within the solution?

Comment: Not within a single git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this: carry each section as a separate branch and have an aggregator branch that records each as a submodule. The helper command doesn't have automation for this but it's not hard.

```
git init myapp; cd $_
for s in section{1,2,3,4,5} master; do
        git checkout --orphan $s
        git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial $s commit"
done
for s in section{1,2,3,4,5}; do
        git worktree add $s $s
        git submodule add ./$s
        git submodule absorbgitdirs $s
done
```

Cloners will need to recreate the worktree setup (with that last `for` loop minus the `submodule add`), put instructions in your `README` or `INSTALL` or whatever, and you'll need to remember to add and commit the new section  versions to master after adding and committing new content to your section histories.